# Convert NSString Value into Date Returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

After converting NSString into Date returns nil.

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
      strDate  = @"05-18-2017 23:03:24";           
     NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

After debugging dateFromString is return nil.
```

I do not have any idea! what went wrong at my end of coding?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

should be

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

As you specify hour in 12 (hh) format and give 23 which is 24 (HH) format

Comment: Its now working HH hh  really makes lot difference.